# Is there a way for JOptionPane buttons to have non consecutive numbers?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So I want to make a program in Java using JOptionPane that’s essentially a choose your own adventure type thing. I was hoping that I could make it simple and use only case and switch. However, that would mean that I need buttons that would be stored as non consecutive values. So that the first button can be stored as the integer 2 and the second button can be stored as the integer 7. I know that it’s possible to make the integers start at a different number other than 0, but do they have to be consecutive? Otherwise, can you do the `if (option == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)` with custom options and/or case and switch?

Here’s an example

```
option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog (“asks a question”);
while (playThis == 1){
>switch (option){
>>case 1:
>>>option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog (“result of questions and asks a question”);\\want this to have the options equal to let’s say 1 or 5
>>>break;
>>case 2:
>>>option = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog (“ result of questions and asks a question”);\\want this to have the options equal to let’s say 2, 3, or 4
>>>break;
\\so on and so forth}}
```

Comment: It is not clear what “button one stored as 2” means.  Edit your question and show the portion of your code which makes use of JOptionPane.

Comment: 1) No you can't control the int value that is returned from the JOptionPane. 2) It doesn't matter anyway if you use a case statement, You just check for sequential values.